# Automated method to add javascripts/css into local html files and execute them

Tags: javascript, html-parsing, watir, automated-tests

I have a set of html files needed to be modified locally. So I found an easy way to do that: write javascript/css, attach them into existing html, run them in a web browser, and save the results back to html files. The problem is I have a very large set of html files to be processed. So I need an automation.

I would love to know how this task should be addressed. I found that there is an automated testing tool like Watir, but still wonder if this is the right option for the problem.

Specifically I use jQuery to easily parse and modify html pages dynamically. This is the reason I don't want to do it otherwise with, for example, Java which lacks support of good libraries for html parsing.

Comment: a "headless browser", like [Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/) may help you.

Comment: @Lee: You should submit that as an answer.

Comment: @Lee PhantomJS seems very promising. I will give it a shot. Please submit your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "headless browser", like [Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/) may help you.